# PL/SQL value of a boolean after execution using SQL%NOTFOUND

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Just started learning about PL/SQL and the cursor attributes.  I am confused to how the SQL%NOTFOUND works.  In the below code should v_1 compile to true at all times?

```
DECLARE
   v_1     BOOLEAN;
   v_2     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT  count(*)
   INTO    v_2
   FROM    t1;

   v_1 := SQL%NOTFOUND;
END;
```

Comment: Yes its actually false not true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `v_1` should always be `FALSE`.  The question being asked by `v_1 := SQL%NOTFOUND` is "Were there no records found by the query?", and the answer to this is "No" (or `FALSE`) because this query will always return a row - therefore, `v_1` will always be `FALSE`.  It's kind of a "double-negative" situation, kind of.  :-)

Share and enjoy.